# What kind of capacitor is this? Can anyone describe the 25u 50v

Tags: capacitor, identification

Is this ceramic or disc capacitor?

And also what do the values "25u 50v" on that component mean?

Why can't I see those values when I search for 104m capacitor?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's ceramic, 0.1uF, 50V, with a Z5U dielectric.

Comment: I confirm I found them from "image" browser search  it is ceramic 0.1µF 50V

Comment: Where can I buy them I'm uanble to find them anywhere

Comment: Try searching for "100nF, 50V ceramic capacitor". Seeking product recommendations and where to buy them are not allowed on EE.SE. See the Help section below.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/60?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv14=238738&pv252=67021&pv69=411897&pv16=392278&pv508=9726&sf=1&FV=-8%7C60%2C7%7C2%2C17%7C423404%2C1989%7C0%2Cmu0.1%C2%B5F%7C2049&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 2):

The 104 is the value code. Similar to the resistor code.

1, 0, 4 zeros, picofarads = 1 0 0000 = 100000 pF = 0.1 uF